# Parse checkIfCommandIsRunning Pausing App

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

For a reason I can't work out, this just started happening out of the blue. Upon launching my iOS app, the app pauses on a breakpoint with the following method:

```
[PFQuery checkIfCommandIsRunning]
```

I believe this is a private Parse method. If I turn breakpoints off it isn't an issue, but something is clearly strange here. I have a breakpoint to trigger on all exceptions. Which is what pauses the app in this case.

### Edit

Here is the method in MY code which the breakpoint stops at. This is listed at 3 method previous to `checkIfCommandIsRunning` in the thread queue.

```
//get objects we want to delete
    [deleteQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            //create array of ids from delete list
            NSMutableArray *deletedObjectIds = [NSMutableArray new];
            for (PFObject *obj in objects) [deletedObjectIds addObject:obj.objectId];

            //update main query to not include these objects
            [_query whereKey:@"objectId" notContainedIn:deletedObjectIds];
        }
    }];
```

What I am doing in this code is simple. I have a `PFQuery` that fetches all objects with a specific `pinName` that I have labeled to be deleted. The exact line it stops on is:

`[_query whereKey:@"objectId" notContainedIn:deletedObjectIds];`

Any more clues?

Comment: why are you calling it?

Comment: I'm not, but this is the method which the breakpoint stops on. As I mentioned, I think its a private Parse method, so its hard work out any meaning of it.

Comment: Can you post where are we in the execution your code when the problem occurs?  Specifically, what calls have been made into parse sdk up to this point.

Comment: I've updated the question with a little more info. Not sure it sheds anymore light sadly. See what you think.

Comment: Prove its not something you did earlier with `_query` by creating a new PFQuery and calling whereKey: notContainedIn: on it, instead of on `_query` (presumably an ivar).  Prediction:  that will work fine, and this will implicate the history of `_query`.  I'll ask you to post everything about it, and we'll find that its already executing when you get to the line that fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct `PFQuery.checkIfCommandIsRunning` is a private method that ensures that a `PFQuery` not not executed more than once on a `PFObject`.

The error it throws is:

> This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait
>   until it's done.

Make sure you are not calling the query more than once at a time by either

- Adding a `Bool` variable `isQueryExecuting` as condition to execute the query and set it to `true` when you start the query, to `false` when the query is done.
- Executing the queries in a serial queue to ensure that a query is only executed after all previous ones are done (FIFO). Consider performance implications here.